# Setting image src using 'this' in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, this

My HTML comprises of multiple `.panorama divs`, holding images:

```
<div id="pan1" class="panorama">
    <img src="images/pano.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div id="pan2" class="panorama">
    <img src="/images/alma.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

I'm currently using the following to store the image src to a variable

```
var imgSource = $(this).find(".panorama img").attr("src");
```

The above is then placed into the following code, to read the image source:

```
if($('.panorama').length >0 ){
    v1 = pannellum.viewer('pan1', {
    "type": "equirectangular",
    "autoLoad": true,
    "pitch": -20,
    "hfov": 110,
    "panorama": imgSource
});

v2 = pannellum.viewer('pan2', {
    "type": "equirectangular",
    "autoLoad": true,
    "pitch": -20,
    "hfov": 110,
    "panorama": imgSource
});
}
```

However, this is just returning `images/pano.jpg` twice and ignoring `pannellum.org/images/alma.jpg`

Am I setting up `$(this)` incorrectly?

Comment: Why `$(this).find(".panorama img")` instead of `$(".panorama img")` ?

Comment: Calling `attr()` on a collection of elements will only return the attribute from the first one in the set. Alternatively the scope of `this` is only finding the first `img` element. Either way you'll need to loop over all the `.panorama img` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you want all images (as you don't actually specify what `this` is in this context).

You don't want `$(this).find(".panorama img")` you just want to use the search term without `this`:

```
var img = $(".panorama img");
```

This returns your images (plural). You have multiple images returned so you need to iterate the sources:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var img = $('.panorama img');

  for(x = 0; x<img.length; x++)
  {
     var imgSource = $(img[x]).attr("src");
     console.log(imgSource);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pan1" class="panorama">
    <img src="images/pano.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div id="pan2" class="panorama">
    <img src="/images/alma.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```